# Repeat same activity

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I'm following this tutorial http://www.sarahghaffary.com/android-quotes-generator-sample-application-using-alarmmanager-and-sqlite-database/, but I want to know how would I make it keep repeating the quotes even if runs out of quotes. I know I need to change the code below but no sure how. Only beginner, Any help would be awesome!

Code:

```
 public String getRandomQuote(){
SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + QUOTES_TABLE_NAME + " WHERE " + KEY_ISREAD + " = 0 ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 1";
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

if (cursor != null)
    if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
        db.execSQL("update " + QUOTES_TABLE_NAME + " set " + KEY_ISREAD + " = 1 where "+ KEY_ID +" = "+ cursor.getString(0));
        return cursor.getString(1);
    }
return "Sorry, you ran out of quotes <img src="http://www.sarahghaffary.com/wp-includes/images/smilies/icon_biggrin.gif" alt=":D" class="wp-smiley"> ";
}
```

Comment: the simple solution is to put KEY_ISREAD back to 0 again.

Comment: the same way you put it to 1, only without a where clause.

Comment: Could you show example, only beginner, sorry :S

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public String getRandomQuote(){
SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + QUOTES_TABLE_NAME + " WHERE " + KEY_ISREAD + " = 0 ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 1";
String UpdateAllQuery= "Update "+ QUOTES_TABLE_NAME + " set " + KEY_ISREAD + " = 0";
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
String quote = "";

if (cursor != null){
        cursor.moveToFirst();  
        if (cursor.getCount() < 1){
            db.execSQL(UpdateAllQuery);
            cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
        }
        db.execSQL("update " + QUOTES_TABLE_NAME + " set " + KEY_ISREAD + " = 1 where "+ KEY_ID +" = "+ cursor.getString(0));
        quote = cursor.getString(1);
        return quote;
}else{
   return "Sorry, you ran out of quotes <img src="http://www.sarahghaffary.com/wp-includes/images/smilies/icon_biggrin.gif" alt=":D" class="wp-smiley"> ";
}
```

Comment: Just shows "Sorry, you ran out of quotes". Thanks for trying :)

Comment: Try it again with the corrected code.  If it was going straight to `Sorry` part then you had a null cursor.

Comment: This gets error on getRandomQuote, it says to add return statement which i did, now just shows nothing in app :S. Thanks a lot for trying again :D

Comment: why the moveToFirst if isLast ?

Comment: Sorry I miss read the SQL statement, Are you using KEY_ISREAD to tell if it has already been shown?  I cannot access the site you were reading from because my work blocks blogs...

Comment: I think it is. I'm using that tutorial in the question

Comment: So how would I do this now?

Comment: This gets error on getRandomQuote, it says to add return statement which i did, now just shows nothing in app again. Thanks a lot for trying again, you have be very helpful :) :)

Comment: This was because there was not return statements on every possible route. Check new answer.